# How can i get an simple calendar window with Javascript in an html page

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am new to JS and I would like to know, How can I get a simple calendar window using JS.
Actually, I want to write a simple function which will get the selected day, so that I can use that date as a string later in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a server side calendar, I just finished one. The only issue is that any interaction with the calendar requires a post back, not optimal.

What are you using for your back end? If it's ASP.NET MVC I will share my partial view for the calendar, you could update it to use a table, shudder, instead of Bootstrap for positioning the days.

Comment: i just want to use it for a simple single HTML page, no interaction at all with servers.

Comment: Your best bet then is to find a third party JS calendar library. A quick Google for JavaScript calendar library should reveal some. It is then a matter of following the library's documentation to get it working. There's usually samples

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery

```
<input type="date" id="calendar" />
<button id="btn">get</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
        var date = new Date($("#calendar").val());
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        alert(day);
        alert(month);
        alert(year);
    });
</script>
```